# vCenter Operations Manager Fault Meaning

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

I am using vCenter Operations Manager to anaalyse my vmWare environment and all looks well. I just have one
fault on one of my servers, it has the following message:

Health of BMC changed from gray to yellow. Sensor name : Integrated Lights Out 2 (iLO 2) (Active).

Does anybody know what this means, I have checked the documentation and googled it and cant get much information.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Gray to Yellow" or "Green to Yellow?"

Regardless, BMC stands for `Baseboard Management Controller` and iLO is HP's Out of Band Management technology.  The warning you're getting it telling you that the server in question is throwing a warning condition, detected by your iLO2 sensor for the Baseboard Management Controller. You should be able to see the warning conditions under the health configuration in vCenter, and track down what's triggering the warning.  We tend to see this a lot when the battery on the RAID controller or CMOS starts to die, or we get voltage variances on the system mainboard due to age.